# Is there a built in arg to json.Marshal a []byte to UTF-8 instead of base64?

Tags: go

My goal is to send a struct in JSON format.

The problem is, the struct's fields are mostly `[][]byte`.

The current solution that I can think of:

1. Reiterate the fields and do `string(field1)`.
2. do `atob(field1)` in the front end.

I think the second solution is the better approach. Anyway, if there is a built in arg to json.Marshal a struct to UTF-8 instead of base64, it would be great.

Reproducible code `main.go`

```
package main

type response1 struct {
    Page   int
    Fruits []string
    Names  [][]byte
}

func main() {
    res1D := &response1{
        Page:   1,
        Fruits: []string{"apple", "peach", "pear"},
        Names:  [][]byte{[]byte("jack"), []byte("james")}}
    res1B, _ := json.Marshal(res1D)
    fmt.Println("res1B", string(res1B))
}
```

Comment: Change `Names` type from `[][]byte` to `[]string`.

Comment: @colm.anseo that require refactoring over 3 packages. I am new to Go, I use pointer and []byte. Now, I regretted it when I need to send the data over the network. Anyway, I assume that therr are no built in arg to do it?

Comment: There's many ways to do this. Depending on how much control you have over the source tree. If you only have access to the marshal endpoint code, a simple conversion and/or custom marshaler may be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can write a custom [MarshalJSON](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-package-CustomMarshalJSON), which will be used in a `json.Marshal` instead of the default action

```golang
type response1 struct {
    Page   int
    Fruits []string
    Names  [][]byte
}

func (r response1) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var names []string
    for _, n := range r.Names {
        names = append(names, string(n))
    }
    return json.Marshal(struct {
        Page   int
        Fruits []string
        Names  []string
    }{
        Page:   r.Page,
        Fruits: r.Fruits,
        Names:  names,
    })
}
```